# On the average length of the Steiner net for $n$ randomly chosen points in the unit square

Tags: probability, geometry, inequality

$n$ points are randomly chosen in the unit square with respect to the uniform measure.

What is the average length $L$ of the associated Steiner net (tree of minimum length through each of the $n$ points)?

---

Heuristics show that we may expect something like $C\cdot\sqrt{n}$: a sub-optimal net is achieved by considering a square spiral with width $\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and connecting every point with the closest point of the spiral. Another natural approach is to consider the boundary of the convex envelope, remove it, consider the boundary of the convex envelope of the remaining points and so on. Divide-and-conquer approaches looks interesting, too. However, despite the fact that $L\ll\sqrt{n}$ is straightforward to prove, I have not managed to prove that $L\geq D\cdot\sqrt{n}$, neither
$$ L\sim C\sqrt{n} $$
with an explicit constant $C$.

---

**Update**: By the [asymptotics on the EMST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree) by Micheal Steele and the fact that the Steiner net is longer than a constant times the length of the minimum spanning tree, we have the double inequality
$$ A\sqrt{n} \leq L \leq B\sqrt{n}$$
with $B\leq\frac{5}{2}$ by my previous construction. It remains to prove that:
$$ L\sim C\sqrt{n}$$
for some explicit constant $C$.

Comment: Don't asymptotics for [Euclidean MST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree)s imply anything?